# Simplexmlelement - how to access the htmltag from the node

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm trying to get status from the following feed.

```
<item>
    <unit:leaseTerm>12 Months</unit:leaseTerm>
    <unit:status><a href="xxxxx">Occupied</a></unit:status>
    </item>

    $feed = new SimpleXMLElement($content);
    $ns = $feed->getDocNamespaces(TRUE);

    $unit_ns = (string) $ns['unit'];

    foreach ($feed->channel->item as $entry) {
     $unit = $entry->children($unit_ns ); 
     $unit_leaseTerm = $unit->leaseTerm;
     $unit_status = $unit->status;

    }
```

I can get the unit:leaseTerm as it is the plain text.

How to access status from the feed?. I want to get 'Occupied' from the node.

Is there anyway to get rid of the html tags while parsing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure whether this works or not just check it

```
$res = $feed->xpath('//unit:status');
echo (string)$res[0];
```

Comment: When I print the  echo "<pre>"; print_r($feed->channel->item); //exit; Status is empty. simplexml doesn't parse the html tag inside the node

Answer (score 0):

**Here's some cheap hax:** (because that XML is pretty frigin malformed)

```
//Cast the values of the Simple XML Object into a associative array
$xmlData = get_object_vars($feed);
//Cast the values of the sub Simple XML object into an associative array
$ocVars = get_object_vars($xmlData['unit:status']);
//And voila! Using "a" index, because that seems to be the "XML" node 
     //contianing the value
$occupiedValue = $ocVars['a'];
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway to get rid of the html tags while parsing?

That is no HTML tag. I mean you read it as one, but technically, this is just an XML tag.

As this XML, the rules with the Namespaces apply:

```
$unit->status
```

Is not having the `<a>` element because the `<a>` element is in different namespace. So it appears as empty string.

However, looking into the default namespace will give you "`Occupied`":

```
$unit->status->children()[0]
```

That's all.